# Implementing views with template in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm struggling to show on a webpage some model objects I created from the admin pages on my site.

I combed through [the relevant django tutorial page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/) but nothing I've tried works to show the model objects on the page.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta



# Create your models here.

def get_deadline():
    return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)

class JobPost(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(default=get_deadline)    
    wordcount = models.IntegerField()
    jobtaken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # client = models.User.username  

    class Meta:
        ordering = (
        # ("jobtaken"),
        ("-created_at"),
    )

    def publish(self):
        self.pub_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Job #{}".format(self.pk)`
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
#from django.contrib.auth.decorators import staff_member_required
from .models import JobPost
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your views here.

# @staff_member_required()
# class JobBoardView(TemplateView):
#      template_name = "jobs.html"
#      posts = JobPost.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('pub_date')

#changed published_date to pub_date in .models
def jobs(request):
    #posts = JobPost.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')

    latest_post_list = JobPost.objects.order_by('-pub_date')


    context = {

        'deadline': deadline,
        'created_at': created_at, 
        'wordcount':wordcount, 
        'jobtaken':jobtaken,
        'JobPost':JobPost,
        'latest_post_list':latest_post_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'jobs.html', context=context)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from jobboard import views
from login import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #re_path(r'^login/$', auth_views.login(template_name = 'accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    re_path(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', include('login.urls')),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('jobs/', views.jobs, name='jobs')
]
```

Here is my template(jobs.html):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if latest_post_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for post in latest_post_list %}
        <li>{{ JobPost }}</li>
    {% endfor %} 
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>No posts are available.</p>
 {% endif %}


{% endblock content %}
```

I tried various templates, including some really simple ones to test, e.g.

```
  {% if latest_post_list %}
    <p>hello</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>No posts are available.</p>
 {% endif %}
```

but everything I try returns the 'else' part of the if statement. Nothing will show the objects on the webpage.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the relationship between the "index" view in the first snippet and the "jobs" view in the third one? And please show your URLs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Added urls.py and took out the irrelevant bits.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Are you going to the /jobs/ path? What *exactly* do you see on the page? In your first template for example, you use `post` as the variable for the for loop but inside you refer to `{{ JobPost }}` rather than `{{ post }}`. And does your base.html have a "content" block? (And are you sure you do actually have JobPost objects in the db?)

Comment: Yes going to the /jobs/ path. It shows the base.html template with "No posts are available" (the result of the else part of the if statement). So the template works, just not to the desired result. I was under the impression that in a for loop, anything at all could be used to replace x in the statement: `for x in y`. Yes I have 4 JobPost objects, created by adding JobPost model to admin.py `from .models import JobPost
admin.site.register(JobPost)`             and then manually creating 4 objects via the admin page.

Comment: Yes but you need to use the same x when you reference it inside the loop: `for x in y: print(x)`, not `for x in y: print(sdfsdf)` which is in effect what you are doing.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've now changed it to `{% if latest_post_list %}
 <ul>
    {% for JobPost in latest_post_list %}
  <li>JobPost</li>
    {% endfor %} 
 </ul> {% else %}...`   but still only shows the else part of the if statement

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted that would be causing this. Have you done something you haven't shown, like for instance redefining the `objects` manager on the JobPost model?

Comment: Nope, haven't done anything like that, as far as I know...

Comment: OK. Let's keep this simple. Open your console with `./manage.py shell` and do `from myapp.models import JobPost` (replacing myapp with the appropriate name, obviously) and then do `JobPost.objects.all()`. What do you see?

Comment: `>>> from jobboard.models import JobPost
>>> JobPost.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<JobPost: Job #13>, <JobPost: Job #12>, <JobPost: Job #11>, <JobPost: Job #10>]>`

Comment: Alternative idea is a name collision in your urls.py file. You're importing multiple views as "views", but each view uses the same variable context. You might try aliasing your imports in urls.py like "from jobboard import views as job_views" and change the url line to "path('jobs/', job_views.jobs, name='jobs')".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoboBear was correct, it was a name collision in the urls.py file. This fixed the error:
change to `from jobboard import views as job_views` and change the url line to `path('jobs/', job_views.jobs, name='jobs')`.

Changing this raised exceptions in the views.py file for all the context dictionary entries except for

```
    context = {

    'latest_post_list':latest_post_list,
}
```

as Ramtin suggested.

Then I changed the template to

```
    <ul>
     {% for post in latest_post_list %}
      <li>{{ post }}</li>
    </ul>
    {% empty %}
     <p>No posts are available.</p>

{% endfor %}
```

as Ramtin suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have a made a few mistakes which I will list below:

1. Your query method is wrong. It should be:

   `latest_post_list = JobPost.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')`

    or 
   `latest_post_list = JobPost.objects.filter(something=something).order_by('-pub_date')`

2. `latest_post_list` is not an object, it is a query of `JobPost` objects. If you wish to iterate them in the template, you can just pass it to the template and do the iteration from the query. However,

```
 context = {

    'deadline': deadline, # you cannot access deadline (which deadline?)
    'created_at': created_at, # same as above
    'wordcount':wordcount, # same as above
    'jobtaken':jobtaken, # same as above
    'JobPost':JobPost, # You are sending the class to the template which is wrong
    'latest_post_list':latest_post_list, # the only thing you need!
}
```

3. If you wish to loop through the objects of the query in the back-end, you have to do the following:

   ```
   for post in latest_post_list:
       print(post.deadline) # will print the deadline of each JobPost one by one
   ```
4. If you wish to loop through the objects of the query and display them in the template, you have to do this:

   ```
   {% for post in latest_post_list %}
       <p>{{ post.deadline }} - {{ post.created_at }}</p>
   {% empty %}
       <p>There is no post yet!</p>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   There is no need to user `if` in the backend or use `{{ JobPost }}`. if the query is empty, the `{% empty %}` will be effective.